# Keep target page stay in jQuery Thickbox after post-back

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net

I have an asp.net page "demo.aspx", that has a normal link called "Demo Link" which uses jQuery Thick box. The page that is wrapped inside the Thickbox is "target.aspx", that has a button "Demo Button" and a label.

If I click on the Demo Link, it show the "target.aspx" wrapped inside the Thickbox nicely. However, If I click on the "Demo Button", Thickbox is disappeared, "target.aspx" is not wrapped in Thickbox anymore, it is displayed like a normal asp.net page.

Here's the mark-up code of demo.aspx:

```
<a href="target.aspx?height=600&width=800" class="thickbox" title="">Testing Thickbox with Post-back</a>
```

Here's the code-behind of target.aspx:

```
Protected Sub btnDemo_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnDemo.Click

    lblDemo.Text = "Hello World!"

End Sub
```

How do I keep target.aspx in the Thickbox after the post-back of itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to jQuery Thickbox page again and found the answer there on the iFramed content example.

I just added "keepThis=true" to the the link:

```
<a href="target.aspx?keepThis=true&height=600&width=800" class="thickbox" title="">Testing Thickbox with Post-back</a>
```

--